# Form is not submitting after validation using jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

I have a form that requires the validation to be done in two steps. The problem is that the form is not submitting to the server after passes the validation. In the same time I want to hide the form after is submitted. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
<form id="career-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="careers.php">
```

**JS**

```
submitHandler: function() {
  $(form).before("<div id='message'></div>");
  $('#message').html("<h2>Successufully submitted!</h2>");
  $(form).hide();
}

var careerForm = {

  showStepTwo: function(form) {
    $("#step-one").hide();
    $(form).show("drop", 1000);
  },

  validateFirst: function() {
    $("#step-two").hide();
    $("button.btn-link").click(function() {
      form.validate("#career-form");
      if ($("#career-form").valid()) {
        careerForm.showStepTwo("#step-two");
      }
      return false;
    });
  },

  validatePostCode: function() {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("postcodeUK", function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}/i.test(value);
    }, "Please specify a valid Postcode");
  },

  validateSecond: function() {
    form.validate("#career-form");
    careerForm.validatePostCode();
    form.addRules("#address", {
      required: true
    });
    form.addRules("#postcodeUK", {
      required: true
    });
    form.addRules("#date", {
      required: true,
      date: true
    });
    form.addRules("#upload-file", {
      required: true
    });
  },

  validate: function() {
    careerForm.validateFirst();
    careerForm.validateSecond();
  }
};
```

Comment: Something looks horribly wrong with your code.  Not only that, it's contained inside your `form` tag instead of a `script` tag.  What is `submitHandler:` supposed to be?  Shouldn't that be _inside_ of your `.validate()` call?

Comment: Is nothing wrong with the code. The javaScript is all in the separate file and inside the validate() function. I have done it this way because I wanted to show only the relevant code.

Comment: Yes, there is something very wrong with the code as you've presented it.  There is no way for anyone to know which parts of your JavaScript are within `.valdiate({})` and which parts are not.  You have also shown no HTML for the form itself.  You need to include enough code to construct a _concise_ demo of your problem and your OP fails in this regard.  Please see http://SSCCE.org